# Move to current location when location button clicked in Esri map

Tags: ios, swift, esri

Need to move to current location in **Esri Map** when user clicked on current location button. I try to find out but not able to find anything about it for **Esri map**

I do following code but it is not working

```
//MARK:
    //MARK: current location button clicked
    func btnCurLoc_Clicked(_ sender:UIButton)
    {
        arcGISMapView.locationDisplay.startDataSource()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the map to automatically zoom to the current location you need to also set the [autopan mode](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_location_display.html#adceb51eab7fcc9d91070d1bc1235323c)on the locationDisplay
to one of the options [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/latest/api-reference/_a_g_s_enumerations_8h.html#a8ecb72d65800db20fc891e215dd2f30f)
The most basic centering one is AGSLocationDisplayAutoPanModeRecenter.

Answer (score 0):

swift 4 and Esri ios SDK 100.1 examples;

```
func locationOpen(){
    self.mapView.locationDisplay.start { _ in
        let x:Double =  (self.mapView.locationDisplay.mapLocation?.x)!
        let y:Double =  (self.mapView.locationDisplay.mapLocation?.y)!
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if (self.mapView.locationDisplay.started == false)
            {
                // permission location

            }
            else
            { // zoom to geometry
                self.mapView.setViewpointCenter(AGSPoint(x: x, y: y, spatialReference: AGSSpatialReference.webMercator()), scale: self.mapView.mapScale, completion: nil)
            }
        }

    }


}
```